# I want to INSERT VALUES but I don't want user to navigate to this page

Tags: php, ajax

I want to INSERT VALUES after user has clicked OK on the confirmation box. Now the confirmation box works well. The only problem I can see is that when the user clicks 'OK' I want the INSERT VALUES to happen on a seperate page (insertQuestion.php) but I do not want the form to be navigated to that page. I want the form to navigate the way it is doing which is either submit to its own page or submit to create_session.php depending on the situation ($action).

So how can I INSERT VALUES into the database without navigating the user to that page (insertquestion.php) after the user has clicked 'OK' in the confirmation box?

below is the javascript code where the confirmation box appears and if confirmation is 'OK', it submits the form:

```
 function showConfirm(){

             var confirmMsg=confirm("Do you want to Proceed" + "\n" );

             if (confirmMsg==true)
             {
             submitform();   
         }
    }

 function submitform()
            {

        var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");

          QandAO.submit();

            }
```

Comment: onclick on the Ok button, you call a js function that does a "ajax" request to send the form data, and while the async request is processing, you can update the page with message like "thanks for your answer"... take a look at e.g. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ or maybe this http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-jquery-tutorials-for-working-with-html-forms

Comment: Please remove all the unnecessary code

Answer (score 2):

Post the form using an ajax request.

A simple example using jQuery

```
$("#yourbutton").click(function() {
   var fieldvalue = $("#inputname").val(); //grab the form value
   $.post("yourpage.php", //send it to yourpage.php
       {
          field1: fieldvalue
       }, function(data) {
         //do something on success
       }
   );
});
```

Comment: I will give it a shot using Jquery, I will get back to you if there are any problems

Comment: I want to know do I actually need the jquery code because I already have the javascript code which shows the confirmation and submits form if confirmation is true, can't I use the javascript functions I already have? I updated question

Comment: I have updated my attempt on it but still cannot get it working. What am I doing wrong? It isn't coming up with the alert 'Your questions have been submitted'.

Comment: @user1304328, Update the form, how you are triggering the show confirm(), thats not how forms are called, use `document.forms('formname')`

Answer (score 0):

Put an 'include' statement in both receiver pages including the submit form page, which should display nothing for the user. So everything goes on the php of the action targeted  page.

Example:

```
#Check if the conditions are required. If they are, $Valid=1. Then do this:
if ($Valid==1) include 'FULLPATH/insertquestion.php';
```

That includes all the code from insertquestion.php in the place where the include is called if the conditions are met. If you haven't included any html before, you could even do this after the include:

```
else header("Location: " . $PHP_SELF);
```